# Trouble with using csv on large data set to separate parameters

Tags: python, csv, large-data

I'm working with a large data set (OMNI) and I'm looking for ways to parse through the data and put each line of data into <strike>an array</strike> a list. I'm fairly new to Python so I'm learning as I go.

here's what I have:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import csv 

#Choose the file that you want to read from
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()


file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
current_file = open(file_path , "r")

#OMNI_2001 = {}

reader = csv.reader(current_file, delimiter= ' ')

output_file = open('newdata.txt','w')
out = csv.writer(output_file)

for row in reader:
    out.writerow(row)
    print row
#print row[0::1]
```

a row of data I read in looks like this:

```
2001 182  0  0 60 60   7   2  71   -695    320  0.22   -173    6.07    5.23    0.46   -2.00    0.69   -1.93    0.38    2.09   331.0  -329.5    24.5    19.8   8.66  101479.  1.90   0.64   2.25   8.0    6.67   29.65    3.55   12.73   -1.78   -0.70   288  -142   146    -3   -22    20    19   0.99
```

but after I output the new data looks like this:

```
2001,182,,0,,0,60,60,,,7,,,2,,71,,,-695,,,,320,,0.22,,,-173,,,,6.07,,,,5.23,,,,0.46,,,-2.00,,,,0.69,,,-1.93,,,,0.38,,,,2.09,,,331.0,,-329.5,,,,24.5,,,,19.8,,,8.66,,101479.,,1.90,,,0.64,,,2.25,,,8.0,,,,6.67,,,29.65,,,,3.55,,,12.73,,,-1.78,,,-0.70,,,288,,-142,,,146,,,,-3,,,-22,,,,20,,,,19,,,0.99
```

What am I doing to cause so many extra commas? also how would I go about removing unneeded entries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your csv file has multiple spaces between items. `delimiter=' '` causes the reader to regard *each* space as delimiting a new column. This is why the rows have so many "extra" columns.

Use [skipinitialspace=True](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) to cause whitespace immediately following the delimiter to be ignored. This will eliminate the bogus extra columns.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import csv 

#Choose the file that you want to read from
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
with open(file_path , 'rb') as current_file:
    reader = csv.reader(current_file, delimiter= ' ', 
                        skipinitialspace=True)
    with open('newdata.txt','wb') as output_file:
        out = csv.writer(output_file)
        for row in reader:
            out.writerow(row)
            print row
            #print row[0::1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your file doesn't really seem to be a CSV file.  I'd recommend using [`loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or [`genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) from the NumPy module, or, if using NumPy is not an option, parsing the file yourself:

```
with open(file_path) as current_file:
    for line in current_file:
        data_row = map(float, line.split())
        # do whatever you want to do with the data
```